# render canvas circle in the centre of the browser window

Tags: javascript, canvas

I can't understand why my code isn't working, 
the circle is being drawn but not in the centre of the canvas, 
and it's much bigger than it should be and pix-elated. 
Any suggestions, help greatly appreciated.

```
// safe code:
(function(global, library){

var spaceTime = function(container){

// if container is global object
if (typeof container === "object"){
  var cHeight = container.innerHeight;
  var cWidth = container.innerWidth;
}
// if container is a div box
else {
  var cHeight = container.style.height;
  var cWidth = container.style.width;
}
console.log("container is an "+typeof container);

// return unique instance each time sT is called
return new spaceTime.init(cHeight, cWidth);


}

// function constructor
spaceTime.init = function(height, width) {
  this.height = height;
  this.width = width;
}



// methods: override the default prototype property
spaceTime.prototype = {

checkDimensions: function() {
  console.log(this.height + this.width);
  console.log(this);
  return this;
},

sequence: function(divide) {

  // var getSize = this.getCentre(divide);
  var grow = this.expand(200);
  var box = this.setCanvas();
  // box.classList.add("box");
  document.body.appendChild(box);

  // nest this in a requestAnimationFrame and pass
  // the grow function to warp radius
  this.drawCircle(box, grow);

  return this;

},

// expands each unique instance.
expand: function(i) {
  i += 1;
  return i;
},

getCentre: function(axis) {
  // width axis
  if(axis === "x"){
    console.log(this.height / 2);
    return this.height / 2;

  }
  // height axis
  else if(axis === "y"){
    return this.width / 2;
  }
  // if undefined or the string doesn't match
  else{
    throw "please input an x or y axis to be proccessed";
  }
},

// canvas context object and it's api methods
drawCircle: function(c, radius) {

   var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

   var x = this.getCentre("x");
   var y = this.getCentre("y");
   console.log(x);
   console.log(y);

   // define the arc path
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
   ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
   ctx.fill();

   // stroke it
   ctx.StrokeStyle = "#aaa";
   ctx.stroke();

   console.log(ctx);
   console.log(radius);

},

// set up the canvas element
setCanvas: function() {
 var c = document.createElement("canvas");
 c.style.height = this.height + "px";
 c.style.width = this.width + "px";

 console.log("new canvas element created");

 return c;
}

}



// override the prototype object with our own one.
spaceTime.init.prototype = spaceTime.prototype;


// reference and expose library to be invoked.
global.sT = spaceTime;


}(window));








// instance 1 of wormhole library
var inst1 = sT(this);

// method chaining
inst1.checkDimensions().sequence();
```

Comment: add some minimal reproducable example (like, on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpsx3L7x/), so community can test it

Comment: http://jsbin.com/qegekelege/1/edit?css,js,output

Comment: Don't size the canvas with CSS. Using CSS will "stretch & squish" the existing canvas pixels to fit into the new size. That's why your circle is distorted. Instead, size the canvas element directly: `c.height=this.height` and `c.width=this.width`.

Comment: hopefully that makes it abit easier for you to test, it's the sequence method i'm calling against the object right at the end of the my js code.

Comment: Mark, that makes total sense. thanks both. sorry I overlooked the css.

Comment: No Problem. :-) Also, when you resize the canvas all content (your circle) will be automatically erased so you must redraw your content whenever you resize. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Didn't you confused x and y axises here?

```
getCentre: function(axis) {
  if(axis === "x"){
    return this.height / 2;

  }
  else if(axis === "y"){
    return this.width / 2;
  }
...
},

drawCircle: function(c, radius) {

    ...

   var x = this.getCentre("x"); // will return this.height / 2
   var y = this.getCentre("y"); // will return this.width / 2
   console.log(x);
   console.log(y);

   ...
}
```

Eh, probably, you shouldn't use `style` attribute when defining canvas size. Look [here](http://jsbin.com/nugenatace/1/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: I did , nice spot. It still isn't working though for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks ankhzet. think that's it.